# Replace default battery status icon

Tags: battery, notification-bar

Is there any way to replace the default battery status icon with percentage values to indicate battery status?

For example as I saw in a [screen shot](http://www.makeuseof.com/tag/create-custom-homescreen-widgets-bits-android/)
[image]

Comment: As far as I know you need a custom-themed ROM.  Possibly just a launcher.  But I don't think you can change that with an app.  You can get widgets that will display it, though.

Comment: I have seen that type of battery icon present on the CyanogenMod ROM.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This [XDA forums thread](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?p=8639993) sounds like what you are looking for. Note that the **apk** has only been tested on Froyo by the author.

Personally i use [Battery Indicator Pro](http://www.appbrain.com/app/battery-indicator-pro/com.darshancomputing.BatteryIndicatorPro), it can also tell you how much time is left on the battery for various usage scenarios.

Answer (score 3):

you would need a custom ROM to change the battery in the notification bar. That information, IIRC, is in android.jar and the images are in framework-res.apk. CyanogenMod, for example, lets you remove the battery image for just the % of the battery remaining. The "other methods" are just "hacks" that change the image at every percentage level, and there has to be an image for each level. So it would need ~120 images (to include the charging states).

From the look of the picture you posted, you are already running a ROM that has a battery mod. You would just now need to create the images you want, and modify the framework-res.apk with the new images.

You may also want to go back through your older questions and mark them as answered. 25% accept rate will turn people away from even answering your question.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same question, and found this app: [Battery Changer](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=jp.ddo.shigadroid.batterychanger&hl=en).

A couple of problems (that I can overlook) are:

1. It doesn't show while the phone is locked
2. It doesn't hide when another app is in full-screen mode